# Ordenar y agrupar PHP y MySql

Tags: php, mysql

llevo unos dias intentando ordenar y agrupar unas facturas de diferentes años.

Ordenando: todo Perfecto.. evidentemente.

```
SELECT * FROM factura WHERE Pagado=0   ORDER BY FechaV ASC
```

ahora intento agrupar tambien por mes y por año para que diferenciarlas y tengo esto:

```
SELECT * FROM factura WHERE Pagado=0 GROUP BY month(FechaV), year(FechaV)  ORDER BY FechaV ASC
```

pero no me devuelve todos los registros...

Sería esto:

```
Año 2020..
NFACTURA      CLIENTE             Importe      Año
Factura 1 ... LELOLO......... .... 5000   08/5/2020
Factura 2 ... Salus Moreno CB ..... 742   02/15/2020
Total ................................................5742

año 2021

Factura 1 ... pepe el del bar ... 25000   20/10/2021
Factura 2 ... Manolo S.L..... .... 2326   23/10/2021
Total ................................................27326
```

sé que tengo algún problema de percepción, pero no veo la forma de hacerlo ....alguna idea??

Gracias....

Comment: ¿Qué registros debe devolver y no devuelve? Si agrupas por mes y/o por año o por lo que sea se supone que deberías aplicar una función de agregación en el `SELECT` para que sume o haga algo con las columnas del mismo grupo.

Answer (score 1):

usa **`select DISTINCT`**

```
SELECT DISTINCT (NFACTURA) 
FROM factura 
WHERE Pagado=0 
GROUP BY month(FechaV), year(FechaV)  
ORDER BY FechaV ASC
```